# Get doctrine outside controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.1

I tried to get doctrine outside controller but something goes wrong and I don't understand why.

So I created a service :

```
services:
    doctrine.service:
        class: App\DesktopBundle\Lib\DoctrineService
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

And the DoctrineService file :

```
namespace App\DesktopBundle\Lib;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class DoctrineService
{
  protected $manager;

  public function __construct(EntityManager $manager)
  {
    $this->manager = $manager;
  }
}
```

And I want to get the doctrine in this file :

```
namespace App\DesktopBundle\Lib\Game;

use App\DesktopBundle\Entity\OnelevelHistory;
use App\DesktopBundle\Lib\DoctrineService;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class OneLevel{
}
```

But I don't know how to call this service created before. Can you help me please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the idea

Comment: What is "something goes wrong" ?

Comment: But how I can : "Call and inject @doctrine.orm.entity_manager direclty" ?

Comment: Forget this. 1st edit your post to show what you trying to do, and the error your are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why didn't you inject orm entity manager directly in your `OneLevel` class?

```
//services.yml
services:
    one_level.service:
        class: App\DesktopBundle\Lib\Game\OneLevel
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]


//App\DesktopBundle\Lib\Game\OneLevel.php
namespace App\DesktopBundle\Lib\Game;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
/* Other class you need */

class OneLevel
{
    /* @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * OneLevel Constructor
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    // The rest of your method ...

    public function exampleMethod()
    {
         /.../

         $this->em->flush();

         /.../
    }
}
```

Comment: @scoolnico, what about if I have some other params in construct of OneLevel : `public function __construct($game_name, $user_id){}` ?

Comment: @user7424312 please edit your post and explain what OneLevel supposed to do. An entity? Controller? Service?